# Apply LOESS filter / regression to all columns of my data frame

Tags: r, filter, loess

I have a data frame containing 100 columns of numerical values, where each column is a different circular shift of the first column. I need to put a LOESS filter on those columns one-by-one. In my context the covariate is simple, just the index `1, 2, 3, ..., <number of rows>`.

How can I obtain the smoothed values in a new data frame? Thank you!

Comment: I explained this all wrong, i have an excel sheet with 100 columns, each column contains data which has been circular shifted to make them different. I would like to apply a LOESS regression to each of the columns separately within R.

Comment: Yes the covariate is like that

Comment: Yes i have read the excel file into R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume your data frame is called `dat`, you can do:

```
## response
vars <- colnames(dat)
## covariate
id <- 1:nrow(dat)
## define a loess filter function (fitting loess regression line)
loess.filter <- function (x, span) loess(formula = paste(x, "id", sep = "~"),
                                         data = dat,
                                         degree = 1,
                                         span = span)$fitted 
## apply filter column-by-column
new.dat <- as.data.frame(lapply(vars, loess.filter, span = 0.75),
                         col.names = colnames(dat))
```

The function `loess.filter` is based on R built-in function `loess`. Have a look at `?loess` if you have never used it. Here, we have used the following function arguments:

- `formula`: we generate the formula on the fly;
- `span`: this controls the smoothing parameter.

We use `lapply` to apply `loess` column-by-column, retaining only fitted / smoothed values. If you have never used `lapply` before, have a read on `?lapply`.

We can customize `span`. You can compare:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(vars, loess.filter, span = 1),
              col.names = colnames(dat))
as.data.frame(lapply(vars, loess.filter, span = 0.75),
              col.names = colnames(dat))
as.data.frame(lapply(vars, loess.filter, span = 0.5),
              col.names = colnames(dat))
```

As we choose gradually smaller `span`, the result is getting closer to original data. But surely, it is also getting more and more jagged.

---

Here is a small example, using `span = 0.75`.

```
## example data
set.seed(0); dat <- as.data.frame(replicate(3, rnorm(10)))
colnames(dat) <- paste0("var", 1:ncol(dat))
```

Original data:

```
> dat
          var1        var2        var3
1   1.68382474 -1.74121307  2.71648728
2  -0.68325574  1.23062681  0.04827926
3   0.50518377  0.28811377  0.01184018
4   0.04106266 -0.85230469 -0.28150053
5   0.19244324  0.25739150 -0.03539714
6  -0.31722642 -1.36826320 -0.68331669
7   1.48740413 -0.05923145  2.13633374
8   0.63805589 -0.70888114 -0.83978457
9   1.42104234  0.75622827  0.83117970
10 -0.55051748 -1.65601708  0.41827418
```

After applying my code:

```
> new.dat
         var1       var2        var3
1  0.85647777 -0.5045655  1.76600194
2  0.56284689 -0.3124571  1.05971504
3  0.26893906 -0.1369094  0.39435505
4  0.09054923 -0.1186259 -0.15040237
5  0.18381641 -0.4725185 -0.04259514
6  0.40755479 -0.4982544  0.23026628
7  0.67075652 -0.4481397  0.30250611
8  0.64421508 -0.4552548  0.41389728
9  0.48725209 -0.5845782  0.44169083
10 0.27764338 -0.7238709  0.44952801
```